# How to create Rest API and add time delay to process?

Tags: java, multithreading, rest, threadpool

I am very new to Springboot. I have created the following rest API. If this API receives multiple requests at the same time, i want it to handle one by one without loosing any requests. I want this service call to be made with delay of 20 seconds if multiple requests are made.

```java
@RequestMapping({"/create"})
public Response processCreation(@RequestBody(required=false) RequestDTO requestDTO) throws Exception {
    Response response = new Response();
    response=interceptorService.interceptData(requestDTO);
    return response;
}
```

Comment: Your question is very unclear, what do you want to achieve differently? 20sec is a big gap for an api call(even 5sec is), and you are not going to lose anything anyways.

Comment: @Aman, i want all the requests received to be in queue and process them one by one. I am using the data from the requests to call another API from my application. I want to call that another API in 20 seconds time interval.

Comment: If so, you should have a way to maintain the list (LinkedList or database may be), then act upon it with a scheduler which runs every 20sec.

Answer (score 0):

I think a better approach is handling this use case in your code level (not through some springboot configuration).

Once you have a request, take all of the relevant parameters and add them to some kind of a queue.
You will have a thread / thread pool that will read from that queue, process the request and send the response.

The request thread will do nothing except scheduling a new task to the queue. The processing will be made by the dedicated threadpool / thread.

Then you can also add that 20-seconds delay you want.